# hasse principle for a number field

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

I am a little bit of a learner in number theory/arithmetic geometry, so feel free to redirect this question to math.stackexchange if necessary.

The question is the following: I know the Hasse principle for $\mathbb{Q}$: it holds if an alg. variety has a point over $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if it has it over the p-adics $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and over the reals.

Recently, I have seen written somewhere "Hasse principle for a number field". Which is the definition  in that case?

Answer (score 2):

Over any global field the Hasse principle is that a point exists iff there's a point over every completion. Ostrowski's theorem says that the only completions of the rationals are the p-adics and the reals, so you recover the principle you know. In general there will be finitely many places over each rational prime $p$ and finitely many infinite places.

Comment: places = ideals? I'm sorry I need you to be pedagogical!

Comment: @IMeasy: A "place" is an equivalence class of absolute values. The infinite places come from the embeddings of the number field into the reals or complexes, and using the induced absolute value. They do not come from ideals. The finite places are by definition given by the absolute values induced by the prime ideals of the ring of integers of the number field. All these facts can be found in any good algebraic number theory book.